# Chromium blocks flash plug-in because it's outdated even after update

Tags: chromium, flash

I do not consider this a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36575/this-flash-plugin-was-blocked-because-it-is-out-of-date). I am not trying to run a specific version of flash, rather I'm trying to run any version, preferably the latest, without Chromium auto-disabling it.

I get a warning stating:

> The Flash plug-in was blocked because it is out of date
>   With two options:
>   [Run this time]  and [Update plug-in]

When I press update plug-in, I get a page with the following info:

> If you are using the open source
>   Chromium browser, please download and
>   install the Flash Player plug-in
>   below.
>
> To learn more about Flash Player and
>   Chromium, see this TechNote.

I tried installing through APT, a couple of things happened, I gave my admin password, and it was all completed succesfully. Restarted Chrome, and the warning persists.

Trying again, I noticed that no matter what version I select, there appears a box under it that reads:

> Browser: Firefox, Mozilla, Seamonkey

Since I'm using Chromium, I guess this might not be the right version. I can not however select a different version. When I go to **about:plugins**, Chromium tells me:

> Flash (2 files) - Version: 10.2.152 Download Critical Security Update
>   Shockwave Flash 10.2 r152

Here's a screenshot of the webpage I get when I click update, and one of my about:plugins. I've tried disabling the first one, without result:

[image: update webpage]

[image: aboutplugins]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:
Had to reboot Chrome (all windows) after disabling the faulty plug in. It works now, no more warnings.